# Stored Procedure in SQLServer user login

Tags: sql-server-2005

I write the procedure for the login where user can give username or emailid to login and password also. my procedure is like this

```
create procedure users_login (@username varchar(50),@password varchar(50),
  @emailid varchar(50),@ret int output)
as
  begin
       select username,password,emailid from users where username=isnull(@username,null) or
        emailid=isnull(@emailid,null) and [password]=@password
       if(@@rowcount >0)
          begin
                set @ret=1
          end
       else
           begin
               set @ret=0
            end
  end
```

is it ok or any modification is there

Comment: "Is it OK" - what are your requirements?

Comment: Mr.Mitch wheat in login page there are two textboxes are there one for
suername and second for password. in firsttextbox user can give username or emailid for login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the query itself there is a problem, you need to put brackets around the `or` statements otherwise the statement will always return a row when the username is a match in the table :

```
SELECT username,password,emailid 
FROM users 
WHERE ( username=isnull(@username,null) or emailid=isnull(@emailid,null) )
      and [password]=@password
```

Secondly you shouldn't be storing the passwords in clear text.  Please read something like this [article on how to salt and hash your passwords](http://www.aspheute.com/english/20040105.asp)

As for style, I personally would not do it this way.  As others have pointed out isnull() in this case is the same as not using it.  You could also short cut the use of @@rowcount by just setting @ret in the select statement.  If it returns no rows then it will not be set so it will achieve the same end.

So I would write it as:

```
create procedure users_login (
                              @username varchar(50),
                              @password varchar(50),
                              @emailid varchar(50),
                              @ret int output
                             )
as
  begin
       set @ret=0
       select @ret=1 
       from users 
       where (username=isnull(@username,null) or emailid=isnull(@emailid,null) 
             and [password]=@password
  end
```

Comment: hi Mr. Andrew Cox i put the brackets around the  or and u said about @@rowcount  i not understand that .i am checking that the select statement contain the row if contain @@rowcount will retun integer.if it contain a value greater than zero then i set @ret =1

Comment: ok thank you Mr. Andrew Cox thank i am going to write like this only

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a SQL guru, so can someone please tell me what...

```
isnull(@username,null)
```

...is meant to accomplish? To me this is equivelant `@username`

Is this Transact-SQL? Couldn't you shrink the SQL down a bit by using the INSERT INTO syntax for @ret and inserting the COUNT of the rows returned?

Are you escaping username, email and hashing password from your website before using it with the SQL?

Comment: it does nothing! i.e. it returns NULL if @username is NULL

Comment: Mr. taspeotis why because if user can give only username then emailid will give error that is why put isnull. if user give username then emailid will be null. why is that wrong Mr. taspeotis

Comment: I thought it did nothing. I'm hoping you're not using it for escaping?